# Class does not exist CORS laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cors

Estou tentando implementar um middleware de cors no laravel, porém está dizendo que minha classe não existe:

> "message": "Class App\Http\Middleware\CORS does not exist",
>       "exception": "ReflectionException",
>       "file": "/var/www/repositorio/jcontrole2_backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
>       "line": 767,

Criei esse arquivo CORS.php em App/Http/Middleware/Cors.php:

use Closure;

```
class CORS {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

        // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin'
        ];
        if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach($headers as $key => $value)
            $response->header($key, $value);
        return $response;
    }

}
```

No meu kernel.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'cors' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CORS'
];
```

E então nas minhas rotas tentei aplicar esse middleware em um grupo de rotas:

```
$this->group(['middleware' => 'cors', ['prefix' => 'api']], function() {
  Route::post('admin/tipo-produto', 'TipoProdutosController@create')->name('cadastrar_tipo_produto')->middleware('checarPermissaoTela');

  Route::put('admin/tipo-produto/{id}', 'TipoProdutosController@update')->name('editar_tipo_produto')->middleware('checarPermissaoTela');

  Route::delete('admin/tipo-produto/{id}', 'TipoProdutosController@delete')->name('deletar_tipo_produto')->middleware('checarPermissaoTela');

  Route::get('admin/tipo-produto', 'TipoProdutosController@search')->name('recuperar_tipos_produtos');
});
```

Comment: Como você criou uma classe nova, pode ser que o Laravel não esteja "enxergando" essa classe, na raiz do seu projeto tente executar os seguintes comandos: composer dump-autoload ou php artisan dump-autoload eles devem atualizar o arquivo classmap de mapeamento de classes do seu projeto.

Comment: quando eu dei composer dump-autoload retornou Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\Users\jsoftwares1\Desktop\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php on line 242

Comment: Deu esse erro mas funcionou, você quer adicionar seu comentário como resposta?

Comment: Adicionei minha mensagem como resposta, que bom que deu certo.

Comment: Apesar do meu middleware continuar dando erro de cors, essa resposta solucionou o problema da classe não encontrada

Comment: Crie uma nova pergunta sobre o erro que esta ocorrendo informando a versão do Laravel, o erro e seu código fonte, acredito que com certeza alguém já deva ter passado por isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você criou uma classe nova, pode ser que o Laravel não esteja "enxergando" essa classe, na raiz do seu projeto tente executar os seguintes comandos:

**composer dump-autoload**

ou

**php artisan dump-autoload**

eles devem atualizar o arquivo classmap de mapeamento de classes do seu projeto.